# Flex buttons and styles

Tags: apache-flex, coding-style, mxml

I am creating a SWF file using a MXML file. The MXML file define several MX:Button and uses an external stylesheet to style them.

There is a problem I am facing at the moment, I am aiming to style the buttons in a way that  is similar to the way I can style HTML button elements. However, I could not achieve such look and feel. For example, I could not find a way to define the color and thickness of the borders for each side of the button (top, bottom, left, right), the background color, the margins, the padding, the width, and the height of the button. Also, selector such as hover, active, focus are not available. I was only able to change the size and the font color of the button successfully.

I know that I might be missing something, so I decided to ask for help. Can anyone provide an example of a style sheet that can override the mentioned attributes.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [Flex Style Explorer](http://examples.adobe.com/flex3/consulting/styleexplorer/Flex3StyleExplorer.html) to visually help you achieving the effect you want to give to your Flex application.

These links also might be helpful :

- [Styling with Flex 3.0 using CSS](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1274964&seqNum=3)
- [Designing Flex 3 skins and styles](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/skins_styles.html)

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, as I was willing not only to change the look, but also the spacing between two each buttons using the margins. However, this is the closest answer. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to look at degrafa skinning too.. You can skin almost any component with degrafa the way you like.. you can even add your own custom css selectors. A few links to get you started with skinning buttons..

http://www.asfusion.com/blog/entry/flex-skinning-with-degrafa-screencast-part-1

http://groups.google.com/group/degrafa/web/round-flex-button-component-skin-sample?version=5

http://blog.vixiom.com/2008/08/05/skinning-a-flex-button-with-one-mxml-file-and-degrafa/

by using degrafa to skin your buttons, you can handle any css selectors and draw the button accordingly with the power of degrafa. Good Luck!

Comment: What you suggested is quite good, but it requires an external library. In my situation, I want to stick to the core API. However, such answer is useful for other projects, and I really appreciate your help

Comment: Well, I understand the issues with using a third party library and I kept away from those for a long time... but now degrafa offers so much... its a default on almost all the flex projects in our company. I say you give it a shot... its totally worth it. Atleast watch the videos on asfusion, the link i gave. Glad to help!